# Create macro upon double click cell display filter in new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a question regarding creating macros whereas the scenarios as follows:

Sheet1
Upon clicking any cell in Sheet1, it will automatically filter based on cell A and B.

Sheet2
Automatically display filtered criteria based on double click from Sheet1

For example: when I double click on C1, on Sheet2 will automatically diplay filtered data based on A1 and B1 and same thing goes to if I double clik on C2 on Sheet2 will automatically diplay filtered data based on A1 and B2.

Really need help from the experts here.

Comment: It can be done with single click at least. Not sure about double click since I assume that's completely reserved for entering a cell to edit it.

Comment: screenshots or mini-text-examples of your data-transformations or filtering goals in a before/after manner are very helpful to understand your goals ;)

Answer (score 3):

This would be the code you need to catch your single-click event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  Debug.Print Target.Address
End Sub
```

This would be the code you need to catch your double-click event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
  Debug.Print Target.Address
  'cancel the double click, prohibiting editng of cell per double-click
  Cancel = true
End Sub
```

I would have helped you with your filtering too, but since you did not paste any code to that, and I don't get how excactly you want what data to be filtered, I'll leave that up to you ;)

*Edit:*

This code can be used for `Worksheet_SelectionChange` and will set a filter based on a valid selection inside the used range. If a filter is already in place, it will be deactivated.

```
  On Error Resume Next
  If Sheet1.AutoFilterMode Then
    'clear existing autofilter
    Sheet1.UsedRange.AutoFilter
  Else
    'setup filter based on selection
    Sheet1.UsedRange.AutoFilter field:=Target.Column, _
                                Operator:=xlFilterValues, _
                                Criteria1:=Target.Value, _
                                VisibleDropDown:=True
  End If
```

Comment: Well I'll be a son of a gun!

Comment: hi again, thank you for your suggestion. Exactly it's about filtering, the link for the file can be found here, http://www.sendspace.com/file/1t19oj whereas it should automatically filter in new sheet based on criteria A1 & B1 upon click or double click

Comment: @user1808404 ok, for the sake of anybody to whom this might be helpful, please post a real filtering example and improve your question. It is not that hard and the least you should do, if you expect someone else to do your work. I edited my answer to include a basic filter based on one cell. You should be able to apply it to your situation, if not, provide a more detailed description of your filtering problem.

Comment: hi again, referring to your previous. I seriously have no idea on how to do it on VBA but if done manually of course I can simply put filter in sheet2 instead it needs to take reference from sheet1 and not by manually filter it sheet2 where I need to select from drop down. http://www.sendspace.com/file/zl2lt1